# how to convert Vector<Vector<String>> to Object [] []?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

i have a dinamical sorter for jTable but problem is that he is working with Object [][] data
mine data is in this format

```
Vector<Vector<String>> data;
```

and i guess i need to cast it to object

```
Object [] []
```

I'm guessing i need to make a double for statement to iterate it and then put it into Object variable. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: you have to create `Object[] []` then loop and for each vector call toArray()

Answer (score 1):

With Java 7 or earlier, you'd have to do something like this:

```
int n = data.size();
Object[][] arr = new Object[n][];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr[i] = data.get(i).toArray();
```

With Java 8 you can do it in one line:

```
Object[][] arr = data.stream().map(List::toArray).toArray(Object[][]::new);
```